# Split array as per values in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like this

```
var aaa = [
  [value1,value2],[0,0]],
  [[value3,value4],[0,1]],
  [[value5,value6],[1,0]],
  [[value7,value8],[0,2]],
  [[value9,value10],[1,1]],
  [value11,value12],[2,0]]
];
```

I want to split this array into multiple arrays as per values `[0,1]`, `[0,2]`, etc.

I.e.

```
array1 = [[value1,value2],[value3,value4],[value7,value8]];
array2 = [[value5,value6],[value9,value10]];
array3 = [[value11,value12]];
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Can you explain how you get from the input to the output? There's no logical way that I can see to treat the second sub array to get what you say you want.

Comment: I think the split should be made by accounting for the first value in the second array. Still, quite confusing.

Comment: actually I am calling some service multiple times & from that I am building this array. Now I want to separate this as per particular values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var aaa = [
[['value1','value2'],[0,1]],
[['value3','value4'],[0,2]],
[['value5','value6'],[1,0]],
[['value7','value8'],[0,3]],
[['value9','value10'],[1,1]],
[['value11','value12'],[2,0]]];

var result = {};

for (var i = 0; i < aaa.length; i += 1) {
    if (!result[aaa[i][1][0]]) {
        result[aaa[i][1][0]] = [];
    }
    result[aaa[i][1][0]].push(aaa[i][0]);
}
```

After that:

```
result[0]; //[[value1,value2],[value3,value4],[value7,value8]];
result[1]; //[[value5,value6],[value9,value10]];
result[2]; //[[value5,value6],[value9,value10]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing this :

```
[['value1','value2'],[0,1]]
```

In this example :
0 tell in which array the value must be stored.
1 tell in which cell of this array it must be stored.

This code would do the work :

```
var aaa = [
    [['value1','value2'],[0,1]],
    [['value3','value4'],[0,2]],
    [['value5','value6'],[1,0]],
    [['value7','value8'],[0,3]],
    [['value9','value10'],[1,1]],
    [['value11','value12'],[2,0]]
];

var arr_result = new Array();

for (var k in aaa) {
    if (arr_result[aaa[k][1][0]] == undefined) {
        arr_result[aaa[k][1][0]] = new Array();
    }
    arr_result[aaa[k][1][0]][aaa[k][1][1]] = aaa[k][0];
}
```

Warning : this could let empty cells, just as in this example, there is no [0,0] cell.